# How can I correctly use the timezone format specifier in a TO_DATE call in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, date-format

I am trying to obtain a `DATE` object with the following statement:

```
TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR')
```

and

```
TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC','YYYY-MM-DD TZH:TZM:SS TZR')
```

But in both cases, it is telling me: `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`.

I got the `TZR` format specifier from https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php, namely:

```
TZD     Daylight savings information. For example, 'PST'
TZH     Time zone hour.
TZM     Time zone minute.
TZR     Time zone region.
```

What is the correct way to specify a date/time with a time-zone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)

> TZR - Time zone region information. The value must be one of the time
>   zone region names supported in the database. Valid in timestamp and
>   interval formats, but **not in DATE formats**.

```
select to_timestamp_tz
  (
    '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR'
  )
  as result
from dual;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
01-JAN-70 12.00.00.000000000 AM UTC
```

If you want a `DATE` type, you need to convert it:

```
select cast(to_timestamp_tz
  (
    '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR'
  ) as date)
  as result
from dual;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
01-JAN-70
```